# Colorizing custom gitmessage file in vim

Tags: shell, vim, vim-plugin

I have a custom `.gitmessage`. It is defined in the git config. I've added a `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim` to redefine a couple of things in the plugin (in support of Conventional Commits), e.g., `textwidth`.

My `.gitmessage` looks something like this:

```bash
#subject-|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|-------->|
# Commit messages should follow the Conventional Commits Specification
# <type>(<optional scope>): <imperative subject>
# empty separator line
# <optional body>
# empty separator line
# <optional footer>
#
# API relevant changes                              || perf     commits improve performance
#   feat commits add a new feature                  || revert   commit, well, revert a previous 
#   fix  commits fix a bug                          ||          commit
...
...
```

where I provide an ASCII "ruler" for 100 chars (though the VIM filetype plugin config autowraps to the `textwidth` per my customization, &tc.

However, I would like to **colorize** the conventional commit sample and the type keywords, e.g., feat, fix, perf, &tc.

I've tried most of standard ASCII escape codes in the `.gitmessage`, e.g., `\\e[1;30m`, `^[1;30m` (Ctrl-V, esc), and `\033[1;30m`. Alas, they all just get dumped to the vim editor—it makes sense that vim would make sure that these codes are editable—but `gitcommit.vim` does colorize the diff in `git commit --all --verbose`...

This appears to be, maybe, a function of `shellescape` (see `:h shellescape` in vim). I see this used in some of the filetype plugins, but I'm not a plugin hacker.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim doesn't care about your escape codes.

A quick and dirty method would be to use `:help :match` or `:help matchadd()` in your custom ftplugin:

[image: :match]

But the real solution is to create your own syntax script, following the instructions under `:help usr_44`. See `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/gitcommit.vim` for a start.

Comment: This is the hint I needed to get started. I'm already writing my `~/.vim/after/syntax/gitcommit.vim` with some initial success!